# decode multiple conditions in oracle/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

i have this table containing:

```
id number = unique per user
code = c (calendar) or f (fiscal)
start_month = 1 to 12
date_created
```

what do i do to decode the period of filing:

e.g. if a user is tagged as C and start_month = 1, then period of filing will be '3' for 1st qtr, 6 for 2nd qtr, 9 for 3rd quarter and 12 for 4th quarter.

if a user is tagged as F and start_month =2, then period of filing will be 1st qtr = 4, 2nd qtr = 7, 3rd qtr = 10, 4th qtr = 1

Comment: let's say table 1 is named table1, my select would be: select id_number, code, start_month, qtr1, qtr2, qtr3, qtr4---the 1st 3 columns will be selected from table1 whereas the value for qtr1-4 should come from using the decode function....can not use the case when function since oracle version am using is a bit old.. :-)

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what I was asking for. I don't understand why `code = C and start_month = 1` gives you `3, 6, 9, 12` while `code = F and start_month = 2` gives you `4, 7, 10, 1`. Could you explain THAT logic (with other cases and, better, a pseudo algorithm). What would happen with `code=F and start_month = 3`, if that's possible ? Or the 2 cases you give are the only one which can exist ?

Comment: sorry...if code is C and start_month = 1, then qtrs(1,2,3,4) will always be 3, 6, 9 and 12..but if code is F and start_month = 2, then qtrs will always be 4,7,10,1...if code is F and start_month = 3, then qtrs will always be 5,8,11,2...if code is F and start_month = 4, then qtrs will be 6,9,12,3...etch...

Comment: So I don't see any difference between C and F with your samples... It looks like only start_month has an impact.

Comment: the value of the qtrs varies depending on the start_month for Fiscal..i dunno how do i apply the decode function.. :-)

Comment: Ok, and it has no impact when it's calendar, then. So if `code = C and start_month = 5`, you will also get 3, 6, 9, 12

Comment: if there is no difference in calendar and fiscal year then you can use decode, else if you have a logical difference then you should go for case statement. Be clear with your logic. Post all the possibilities in test case

Comment: can you help me with the decode function then? how do i use the decode function to arrive at the desired period per qtr?

Comment: thanks for helping me out guys..appreciate the response..so thankful  :-) :-) :-)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus, i have to derive the value for the field quarters for fiscal...note that quarters is not defined as a column in the above table...thanks again..

Comment: @realspirituals, can't use the case statement...oracle am using is a bit old... :-)

Comment: What version you are running in

Comment: Oracle supports CASE since 8i, which was released in 1997. So, you are using a version prior to that??!!

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to convert start_month to a date and use add_months(), but of course if you can't use case then your version is older than 8i and you won't be able to use add_months() either.

Any mathematicians out there will rightly be horrified by the following use of div and mod 13, but if I'm understanding correctly what you're trying to achieve, I think this would work in Oracle 7 and probably older versions:

```
select decode ( code, 'c', 3,
                      'f', trunc((2+start_month)/13) + mod((2+start_month),13)) as qtr1,
       decode ( code, 'c', 6,
                      'f', trunc((5+start_month)/13) + mod((5+start_month),13)) as qtr2,
       decode ( code, 'c', 9,
                      'f', trunc((8+start_month)/13) + mod((8+start_month),13)) as qtr3,
       decode ( code, 'c', 12,
                      'f', trunc((11+start_month)/13) + mod((11+start_month),13)) as qtr4,
etc...
```